# How do you lossily compress a video track from a media device in a browser?

Tags: javascript, browser, html5-video, webrtc, video-compression

I want to compress this track into another track that I can send over WebRTC via addTracks. How would I do this? Was hoping there was an easy option built into the browser

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by using constraints. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Streams_API/Constraints. I can reduce the framerate and the resolution (via height/width).

Answer (score 0):

You can do mixing of audio with webaudio and video with a combination of canvas and captureStream.

[Here](https://en.slideshare.net/KevinSimons/its-all-coming-together-mcu-in-javascript) is an old presentation, sadly the talk wasn't recorded.